# Console App error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#

Hey all I am trying to get the following code to work but currently I am getting this error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'fetchFeedData.Program.txtUsername'

The code is:

```
class Program
{
    private string appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\feedReader";
    internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();
    private WebClient imageClient;
    private String txtUsername = "xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com";
    private String txtPassword = "xxxxxxx";
    private Boolean chkDownVideo = false;
    private Boolean chkIsHD = false;

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   bool isNew;
   Mutex mtx = new Mutex(true, "FacebookNewsfeedReader", out isNew);

   if (isNew) {
     InitializeXul();
     LoadSettings();
   } else
     MessageBox.Show("Already one instance is running.....", "Facebook Newsfeed Reader");
}

static void LoadSettings()
{
   imageClient = new WebClient();
   imageClient.Headers.Add("Accept", "image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
   imageClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36");
   imageClient.Headers.Add("Referer", "https://www.zzzzzzzz.com/");
   imageClient.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
   imageClient.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");

   string[] vals = data.Split('\n');
   if (vals.Length < 3)
      return;
   txtUsername = vals[0];
   txtPassword = vals[1];
   txtBrowseFolder = vals[2];
   chkDownVideo = bool.Parse(vals[3]);
   chkIsHD = bool.Parse(vals[4]);
}
```

It shows that same error on the following lines:

```
imageClient = ...
imageClient.Headers.Add(...
imageClient.Headers.Add(...
imageClient.Headers.Add(...
imageClient.Headers.Add(...
imageClient.Headers.Add(...

appDataPath + ...
txtUsername = ...
txtPassword = ...
txtBrowseFolder = ...
chkDownVideo = ...
chkIsHD = ...
```

I searched a little and found continued suggestions to make sure both had the same function calls (static, void, etc) but that did not seem to fix the issue.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the other commentors- what's really missing here is an understanding of what the [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) keyword means and what it means to instantiate objects.

The specific issue here is that your `Program` class's fields requires an instance before they can be accessed (`Program` and it's fields are not static) while your `Main` method is `static`.

In other words either:

1. Change `Program` and it's fields to static: `static class Program`
2. Instantiate `Program` in `LoadSettings` before using it:

   ```
   static void LoadSettings()
   {
       //...
       Program p = new Program();
       p.txtUserName = vals[0];
       //...
   }
   ```

Comment: @StealthRT @L.B There's an ongoing debate about the minimal amount of knowledge a question must show (e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257874/251983) - To be fair, your question is very close to this line.  `static` vs. `instance` is a core concept of **any** Object Oriented language. That said, this tripped me up in another life when I was getting started and you did show some effort in listing your code, but it appeared you didn't know where to begin searching for the problem-hence my decision to answer (and hence the minimal knowledge debate ;0) -Keep practicing, but do some reading! :)